# Why isn't my code toggling properly when I try it with multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just a newbie and I'm trying to learn jQuery and JavaScript so I thought to develop a memory card for learning languages project to just get used to it, my code creates a new card and shows it without storing any data and refreshing the browser and it has to, right now I completed the delele functionality though toggling doesn't always work properly, could you help me to figure out why?

Here following is my code:

```js
function reloadData(el) {
  $("#content").html("");

  for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    $("#content").append(el[i])
  }

  var cards = $(".card");
  var deleteButtons = $(".delete");

  for (let x = 0; x < cards.length; x++) {
    deleteButtons[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var result = [];

      for (let p = 0; p < cards.length; p++) {
        if (p == x) {
          continue;
        } else {
          result.push(cards[p]);
        }
      }

      reloadData(result);
    });
  }
}

$("#createCard").click(function() {
  var a = $("#txt1").val();
  var b = $("#txt2").val();

  $("#content").append(
    "<div class='card' style='float: left; width: 100%; height: 35px;'><div class='words' style='float: left; width: 70%;'><p style='float: left;' class='original'>" + a + "</p><p style='float: left; display: none;' class='translation'>" + b + "</p></div><div style='float: left; width: 30%;'><a class='toggle'>ruota</a><a class='delete'>elimina</a></div></div>"
  );

  var cards = $(".card");
  var deleteButtons = $(".delete");
  var toggle = $(".toggle");
  var words = $(".words");

  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    toggle[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var original = words[i].getElementsByClassName("original")[0];
      var translation = words[i].getElementsByClassName("translation")[0];

      if (original.style.display == "none") {
        original.style.display = "block";
        translation.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        translation.style.display = "block";
        original.style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var result = [];

      for (let x = 0; x < cards.length; x++) {
        if (x == i) {
          continue;
        } else {
          result.push(cards[x]);
        }
      }

      reloadData(result);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Memory cards</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Crea le tue memory card</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" placeholder="originale" />
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" plaecholder="traduzione" />
    <input id="createCard" type="button" value="Crea" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancella" />
  </form>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- inserisci le tue memory cards temporanee qua -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *though toggling doesn't always work properly*: what are you expecting it to do and what's it actually doing?

Comment: To toggle a specific elemet when I press the button "ruota" meaning rotate, with two elements it doesn't toggle the first one, only the second memory card for instance although it get the correct index always the function.

Comment: You're only ever referring to the first card: `var original = words[i].getElementsByClassName("original")[0];` Perhaps you want to iterate over `var original = words[i].getElementsByClassName("original");`?

Comment: It's the same also if I loop through the entire class in this case.

Comment: Please update the post in your code to demonstrate.

Comment: Every time you create a new card, you loop over all the cards adding click event listeners to their delete and toggle buttons. So when you click on an older tioggle button, it will run the toggle code multiple times. If it has an even number of listeners, they'll cancel out and nothing is changed.

Comment: You should only add the event listeners to the card that you just changed. Or use event delegation instead of adding event listeners every time.

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: Set a single event handler on a common ancestor element of all the cards and handle the event there. [See this for details.](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question nor the link I got closed the post because they thought it was a duplicate, I'll go search for help somewhere else.